# What's the investigative process for suspicions of fraudulent votes by proxy at the polling station level in the Netherlands?

Tags: election, netherlands, election-fraud

According to [a recent article by Dutch public broadcaster NOS](https://nos.nl/artikel/2422200-burgemeester-bergen-op-zoom-doet-aangifte-vanwege-vele-volmachtstemmen), two mayors have reported suspicions of election fraud because of the high percentage of votes by proxy in certain polling stations. The article states that this report is a standard procedure prescribed by the *Kiesraad* (the national electoral committee).

According to [an article by Omroep Brabant](https://www.omroepbrabant.nl/nieuws/4059438/mogelijk-geknoei-met-volmachten-burgemeester-bergen-op-zoom-doet-aangifte) the parquet has until next week to investigate these reports.

I wonder what the investigative process looks like. For example, is it normal procedure to ask (some of) those who voted by proxy whether they did so by their own choice?

Answer (score 2):

According to a [follow up article by public broadcaster NOS](https://nos.nl/artikel/2422476-geen-sprake-van-stemmen-ronselen-in-bergen-op-zoom) ([translated to English](https://nos-nl.translate.goog/artikel/2422476-geen-sprake-van-stemmen-ronselen-in-bergen-op-zoom?_x_tr_sl=nl&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp)), the investigation in the city of Bergen op Zoom found no irregularities. Specifically, the article mentions that in the relevant polling places:

- No voters cast more than three additional proxy votes, which is the maximum number allowed.
- A number of those who voted by proxy were interviewed and they provided investigators with convincing reasons for voting by proxy.

As such, this alleviated the concern that proxy votes may have been recruited unlawfully.